# docker-compose - how to make a container a no-operation container?

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that defines a web service and a database.

This file describes my primary use case which is started with `docker-compose up`.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webservice:
    image: my-webservice
    ports:
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
  db-container:
    image: my-database
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

I have an alternate scenario in which I connect the web service to an existing database.

This alternate configuration is invoked with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f use-existing-db.yml up`.

### use-existing-db.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webservice:
    volumes:
    - /some/dir/db.prop:/config/db.prop
```

### My Question

In the scenario that I have described above, the db-container does not need to be started.

I know that I could create a separate docker-compose file that would only start the web service.  I would like to find a solution that overrides the primary docker-compose file.

Is there a good practice for making a specific container into a no-operation container via docker-compose?  I presume that I would simply reference a different image name.

Comment: what purpose does alternate configuration serve? and how does web service connect to an existing database in `use-existing-db.yml`? which database? External, not containerized one?

Comment: use-existing-db.yml uses an external, non-containerized db.  A url for that database is passed in via db.prop.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I have used in the past would be to explicitly state only the subset of the service(s) you want to `up`.

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f use-existing-db.yml up webservice`

If `webservice` were to have a dependency (`depends_on`) on `db-container`, you could do:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f use-existing-db.yml up --no-deps webservice`

Comment: Thanks.  It is helpful to know that the up command can be called selectively for specific containers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution with [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) that will do what you want.

Any container that has a profile attach to them will not be started by default. They will be started if they are explicitly named or if their profile(s) are passed to the command line.

Simply add a profile to the database container:

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webservice:
    image: my-webservice
    ports:
    - published: 8080
      target: 8080
  db-container:
    image: my-database
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    profiles:
      - full
```

Whenever you do:

```
docker compose up
```

You will be starting **only** the `webservice` container.

If you want to start both containers simply add the profile:

```
docker compose up --profile full
```

Or just name the containers to start:

```
docker compose up db-container
```

You should also be able to chain multiple config files (`-f use-existing-db.yml`).